# Force Collapse on Accordion

Tags: accordion

I am new to the coding world and have been teaching myself through internet searches and experimentation; however, I've banged my head against this one for a while and have no solution. I work for a small non profit and am pulled in a dozen directions so I was hoping someone in this great community could help.

I have this accordion that I've set up and used for other pages on our site but now I want to be able to make it so only one of the tabs can be opened at a time. I know the code isn't great but it's what I've made work and find works on our wordpress site with the theme we have (the accordions they have built into the theme aren't great).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.accordion-2 {
    background-color: #e38854 ;
    font-family: lato;
    font-wtight: bold;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 20px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    margin-top: 0px;

}


.accordion-2:after {
    content: '+';
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size; 16px;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 15px;


}

.active, .accordion-2:hover {
    background-color: #c88862;

}

.active, .accordion-2:hover {
font-color: white;

}

.active:after {
    content: "-";
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.panel {
    padding: 0px 10px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    font-family: lato;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<button class="accordion-2">Heading 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5;">
  Text 1<p></span></p>
</div>

<button class="accordion-2">Heading 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5;">
  Text 2<p></span></p>
</div>

<button class="accordion-2">Heading 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5;">
  Text 3<p></span></p>
</div>

<button class="accordion-2">Heading 4</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5;">
  Text 4<p></span></p>
</div>

<button class="accordion-2">Heading 5</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5;">
  Text 5<p></span></p>
</div>

<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-2");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";

    } 
  });
}



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Code relevant to your question belongs directly _into_ your question, not just dumped on an external site.

Comment: My mistake, I'll figure that out now!

Comment: Okay, I fixed it, my apologies!

Comment: Well you would have to loop over all other items and remove the active class from them, when you handle the click on one of those items. Or you store the reference to the last opened item in a variable, so that you can remove it specifically from that one then, if you don’t want to loop over all items.

Comment: Sorry, since I barely know code, I'm not sure what you mean. I think I get it logically but I'm not sure how I would code it.